# Unable to get 2 sub-windows to pop up simultaneously in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr

I am unable to get to sub-windows to popup simultaneously when running my program.  I am able to get one window to popup and then the other window to popup after I close the first window.  This repeats in a loop. I am new to visual studio and C++ so any help would be appreciated.  I am using the auto-generated windows forms to create my blank forms which are under the "CLR" tab of visual studio.

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include "MyFormNoFrame.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace windowsproject;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main() {
MyForm a;
MyFormNoFrame b;
while (1 == 1) {
    b.ShowDialog();
    a.ShowDialog();
}
return 0;
}
```

MyForm and MyFormNoFrame are the two .h files that contain the formatting and design for the popup windows. I created a simple loop to show both of the forms but they popup separately after I close one another.  Is there any way to get them to pop up at the same time?

Comment: what is `MyForm`? Did you write it? If yes then you should know why it blocks until you close the window

Comment: Thanks for the reply. MyForm is the auto-generated file for a blank windows form in visual studio.  I did not write it but I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs come in two flavors, modal and modeless. A modal dialog must be closed before processing can continue. This makes the code a lot simpler. With a modeless dialog, things can happen in the dialog as well as elsewhere. And with two modeless dialogs, there are even more possibilities.

Your code clearly uses modal dialogs, even though you don't show us how you create those dialogs. This is obvious from the behavior you describe. `a.ShowDialog()` waits for the modal dialog to close.

Note that all dialogs are windows, but not all windows are dialogs. You can create your own window entirely from scratch, and implement whatever behavior you want. Dialogs are basically windows where the OS itself supplies much of the behavior. The `MessageBox` dialog is an extreme case, where you just provide the content, no code at all.